# how to query hstore in typeorm?

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I have stored the following object in hstore data type in Postgres

> "verified": {
> "dob": "true",
> "name": "false",
> "email": "true"
> },

How can i query where "dob" = "true"?

Comment: Any example of query that you're making?

Comment: That's not a hstore value - that looks like a JSON value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write the clause as a string:

```
this.yourEntityRepository.find({ where: "verified -> 'dob' = TRUE" })
```

or

```
this.yourEntityRepository.createQueryBuilder().where("verified -> 'dob' = TRUE").getMany()
```

Comment: can u write the same in query builder

Comment: I added an example with queryBuilder